# Applescript can't open app

Tags: cocoa, applescript

I've written a Mac app that isn't scriptable (yet), and I'd like to run it with Applescript. Either of the following scripts get "An error of type-10660 has occurred.". After hours of searching, I haven't found a solution, or an explanation of the error.

```
if exists application "RotorDCU" then
    display dialog "Found." buttons {"OK"}
else
    display dialog "Not found." buttons {"OK"}
end if

tell application "RotorDCU"
    activate
end tell
```

Comment: The "xcode" tag is for questions about the IDE itself, not for any Mac-related programming questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error -10660 is a Launch Services error, explained in the interface file `LSInfo.h`:

> The app cannot be run when inside a Trash folder

Is `RotorDCU` in the Trash, perchance?

Comment: I'm well and truly impressed! Nothing I searched for turned up LSInfo.h. And yes, RotorDCU was in the trash. Emptying it allowed the "activate" script to execute. The "If exists" now says "RotorDCU got an error: Can't continue exists." A curiosity, but not a big deal.